# Mule rounding issue with JSON to object transformer

Tags: mule, rounding, transformer-model, anypoint-studio

I have a JSON to object transformer that follows the datamapper in a Mule 3.6 workflow and found that the JSON to object transformer removes trailing zero in decimal fields so 11.00 becomes 11.0.

How can I prevent the JSON to Object transformer from dropping the last decimal place if it is a zero and enforce 2 decimal places so it will return 11.00 as this is a requirement?

An example flow showing the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_JSON" transformationGraphPath="csv_to_json.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_JSON"/>
    <flow name="deimal-point-flowFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="${file.unprocessed.location}" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" moveToDirectory="${file.unprocessed.location}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="test.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_JSON" doc:name="CSV To JSON"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The test.csv file looks like this:

```
DeptID,Dept,Staff
5LL/A,Human Resources,4.00
```

Comment: I've found that I can use the jackson object mapper to retain the 2 decimal places, but it changes the values to strings.  Is there a way to use the jackson object mapper but retain field values as decimals?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom function that rounds your data, that can be used by datamapper. First add a configuration on your flow, to extend the expression language.

```
  <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
     <expression-language autoResolveVariables="true">
      <import name="dataformatter" class="com.utils.DataFormatter" />
      <global-functions >
          def (value, places) { return dataformatter.round(value, places) }
       </global-functions>
      </expression-language>
    </configuration>



//package com.utils.DataFormatter
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

From that code you could directly call the function and round it properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The issue is with the JSON to Object transformer.  The output from the datamapper shows the correct rounding but then loses the last decimal place when the JSON to Object transformer comes into play.